# Cross-Refs: Sublabel-Skipping Variants

Tags: cross-referencing, linguex, zref

While cross-referencing linguistic examples, I am using `zref` to define commands for referring to pairs or ranges.

For each command I have two "skipping" variants `mainskip` and `maxskip`, meant to be used for local referencing in an unambiguous context; they skip one or two tokens, respectively.

My question is this one: rather than multiplying commands, I would like to turn those variants into optional arguments of the referencing commands:

```
\cleverange[mainskip]{Ref1}{Ref2}, \cleverange[maxskip]{Ref1}{Ref2}

\clevepair[mainskip]{Ref1}{Ref2}, \clevepair[maxskip]{Ref1}{Ref2}
```

Of course it may apply to regular referencing as well, which does not involve ranges or pairs.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{philex}

\renewcommand{\label}{\zlabel}

\newcommand{\na}{n\textbackslash a}

\makeatletter

\zref@newprop{theexno}{\arabic{ExNo}}
\zref@newprop{thesubexno}{\arabic{altsub}}
\zref@newprop{theexdepth}{\theExDepth}

\zref@newprop{mainstrip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\alph{altsub}.\roman{altsubsub}\else\alph{altsub}\fi}

\zref@newprop{maxstrip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\roman{altsubsub}\else{\ifnum\theExDepth=2\alph{altsub}\else\arabic{ExNo}\fi}\fi}


\zref@newprop{mainskip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=1\arabic{ExNo}\else{%
    \ifnum\theExDepth=2\alph{altsub}%
    \else\alph{altsub}.\roman{altsubsub}\fi}%
    \fi}
    
\zref@newprop{maxskip}{\ifnum\theExDepth=3\roman{altsubsub}\else{%
    \ifnum\theExDepth=2\alph{altsub}\else\arabic{ExNo}\fi}%
    \fi}%


\zref@addprops{main}{theexno,thesubexno,theexdepth,mainstrip,maxstrip,mainskip,maxskip}


% Clever Stripping

\newcommand{\pairequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref{#1},\,\zref[maxstrip]{#2})%
            \else (\zref{#1},\,\zref[mainstrip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else (\zref{#1}) and (\zref{#2})\fi}%
            
\newcommand{\rangeequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref{#1}--\zref[maxstrip]{#2})%
            \else (\zref{#1}--\zref[mainstrip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else(\zref{#1})--(\zref{#2})\fi}%
        
\newcommand{\cleverange}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\rangeequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else(\zref{#1})--(\zref{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\clevepair}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\pairequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else(\zref{#1}) and (\zref{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\xzref}[1]{(\zref{#1})}
% Skipping Variants

% A. Main Skip

\newcommand{\mainskippairequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref[mainskip]{#1},\,\zref[maxstrip]{#2})%
            \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1}) and (\zref[mainstrip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1},\,\zref[mainskip]{#2})\fi}%
            
\newcommand{\mainskiprangeequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref[mainskip]{#1}--\zref[maxstrip]{#2})%
            \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1})--(\zref[mainskip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1}--\zref[mainskip]{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\mainskipcleverange}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\mainskiprangeequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1}--\zref[mainskip]{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\mainskipclevepair}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\mainskippairequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else (\zref[mainskip]{#1},\,\zref[mainskip]{#2})\fi}


% B. Max Skip

\newcommand{\maxskippairequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}%
            {\ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref[maxskip]{#1}) and (\zref[maxskip]{#2})%
            \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1}) and (\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1},\,\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}%
            
\newcommand{\maxskiprangeequal}[2]{%
        \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexno}{%
            \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{thesubexno}=\zref@extract{#2}{thesubexno}(\zref[maxskip]{#1})--(\zref[maxskip]{#2})%
            \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1})--(\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}%
        \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1}--\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\maxskipcleverange}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\maxskiprangeequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1}--\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}

\newcommand{\maxskipclevepair}[2]{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{#1}{theexdepth}=\zref@extract{#2}{theexdepth}\maxskippairequal{#1}{#2}%
    \else(\zref[maxskip]{#1},\,\zref[maxskip]{#2})\fi}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\phildashes{}{.} 
\subformat{a}{}{.}     


\lb{main1}{Example One.
    \lba{sub11}{Subexample One-One.
        \lba{subsub111}{Subsubexample One-One-One.}
        \lbb{subsub112}{Subsubexample One-One-Two.}
        \lbz{subsub113}{Subsubexample One-One-Three.}}
    \lbz{sub12}{Subexample One-Two.
        \lba{subsub121}{Subsubexample One-Two-One.}
        \lbz{subsub122}{Subsubexample One-Two-Two.}}}

\lb{main2}{Example Two. 
        \lba{sub21}{Subexample Two-One.}
        \lbz{sub22}{Subexample Two-Two.}}

\vspace{3ex}

\textbf{Clever Ranges} (full - mainskip - maxskip)\vspace{1ex}

\begin{tabular}[c]{lll}

\cleverange{main1}{main2} & \na & \na\\

\cleverange{sub11}{sub12} & \mainskipcleverange{sub11}{sub12} & \na\\

\cleverange{sub11}{sub22} & \na & \na\\

\cleverange{subsub111}{subsub113} & \mainskipcleverange{subsub111}{subsub113} & \maxskipcleverange{subsub111}{subsub113}\\

\cleverange{subsub113}{subsub122} & \mainskipcleverange{subsub113}{subsub122} & \na

\end{tabular}

\vspace{2ex}


------------------\vspace{2ex}

\textbf{Clever Pairs} (full - mainskip - maxskip)\vspace{1ex}

\begin{tabular}[c]{lll}

\clevepair{main1}{main2} & \na & \na\\

\clevepair{sub11}{sub12} & \mainskipclevepair{sub11}{sub12} & \na\\

\clevepair{sub11}{sub22} & \na & \na\\

\clevepair{subsub111}{subsub113} & \mainskipclevepair{subsub111}{subsub113} & \maxskipclevepair{subsub111}{subsub113}\\

\clevepair{subsub113}{subsub122} & \mainskipclevepair{subsub113}{subsub122} & \na

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So basically your question is about how with a command that takes an optional argument it can be checked whether that optional argument equals one or none of the  phrases "mainskip", "maxskip" and forked accordingly? Do you wish pre-processing of the optional argument before checking - e.g., expanding things and/or removing surrounding space-tokens? How fool-proof shall the checking-mechanism be? E.g., what shall happen with "malicious" input like `\cleverange[unbalanced \fi and unbalanced \csname]{...}{...}` ?

Comment: I am completely new at defining options. I want [mainskip] or [mainskip=true] to be identified and then fork the command, I guess.

Comment: These are not "options". These are "optional arguments". Packages/documentclasses in LaTeX have options. ;-) "mainskip=true" is of pattern "key=value". Such a thing is called key-value-interface or key-val-interface. There are several packages available that provide infrastructure for key-value-interfaces. E.g., the good old package [keyval](https://ctan.org/pkg/keyval) written by David Carlisle. E.g., the package [xkeyval](https://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval). E.g., the package [pgfkeys](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys). E.g., [l3keys](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) which is part of the expl3-bundle.

Comment: With some of those "key=value"-packages some distinguishing of the "type" of the value is provided and you can easily declare a "boolean key" where you can provide values like "true" or "false" and specify the default value e.g. to be "true" in case the key is provided without value. If you choose to do so, then "mainskip" and "mainskip=true" trigger the same. Be aware that with most key=value-interfaces "default-value in case the key is provided without value" is not the same as "default in case some key/keys is/are not provided at all".

Comment: Don't add always your complete current implementation to your questions, they get longer and longer  and I at least then simply stop to read them. A minimal example should concentrate on the relevant parts.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I understand. The idea of the question itself is to go a bit further in my "implementation", but the post as a whole was equally meant to be informative. I hesitated before posting it in that shape and had been wondering which was the best way. My first idea was to ask a question, then answer it myself. I know there are articles too, but I guess they are much more advanced. So next time I wish to share some coding I'll ask a question and answer it right away I think.